# How to configure options for Firebase 2nd gen scheduler functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am migrating some scheduler functions from 1st to 2nd gen. While the documentation talks about passing runtime options to other types of functions like `onRequest` and `onCall`, I do not see the equivalent for `onSchedule`. The first argument is the schedule itself and the second is the handler.

So how do I specify things like vpcConnector and memory?

I do not want to use the `setGlobalOptions` function because not everything I want to set should affect all functions globally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [API documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/2nd-gen/node/firebase-functions.scheduler).  There are two variants of onSchedule.  You want [the one that takes ScheduleOptions as a first parameter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/2nd-gen/node/firebase-functions.scheduler.md#scheduleronschedule).  [ScheduleOptions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/2nd-gen/node/firebase-functions.scheduler.scheduleoptions) lets you provide the [schedule](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/2nd-gen/node/firebase-functions.scheduler.scheduleoptions.md#schedulerscheduleoptionsschedule) as a property, along with all of the properties inherited from [GlobalOptions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/2nd-gen/node/firebase-functions.globaloptions.md#globaloptions_interface).  GlobalOptions accepts [vpcConnector](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/2nd-gen/node/firebase-functions.globaloptions.md#globaloptionsvpcconnector) and [memory](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/2nd-gen/node/firebase-functions.globaloptions.md#globaloptionsmemory).

```
exports.mySchedule = onSchedule({
    schedule: "...",
    vpcConnector: "...",
    memory: ...
}, ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

The first argument can be a schedule string but it can also be an object with arguments:

```
exports.schedule = onSchedule({
  schedule: 'every day 00:00',
  memory: '1GiB',
  ... etc
}, async (event) => {
  ...
})
```

You can find all props available on [ScheduleOptions interface](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/2nd-gen/node/firebase-functions.scheduler.scheduleoptions?hl=pt-br) wich extends [GlobalOptions interface](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/2nd-gen/node/firebase-functions.globaloptions.md?hl=pt-br#globaloptions_interface).